# Html in react float-left is not working

Tags: html, css, reactjs, browser

[image]float:right is not working in html in react, I tried all other solutions on other duplicates and still not working:

```
    export default props => (
      <div className="App" style={{float:'left'}}>
        <div className="Task" style={{overflow:'hidden',float:'left'}}>                                                                                                                                                                                                    
          <div className="container">
            <div className="info">
              <div className='project'>{props.project.name}</div>
              <div className='user-fname'>{props.user.first_name}</div>
            </div>
            <div className={'status '+props.status}>{props.status}</div>
            <div>
              <div>estimated:    {props.estimated_time_hours+' : '+props.estimated_time_minutes}</div>
              <Circle
                percent={getEstimation(props.estimated_time_hours, props.estimated_time_minutes, props.total_spent_time)}
                strokeWidth="6"
                style={{height:60}}
                trailWidth="4"
                trailColor="#D3D3D3"
                strokeColor={getColorEstimation(props.estimated_time_hours, props.estimated_time_minutes, props.total_spent_time)}
              />
              <div>spent:         {Math.floor(props.total_spent_time/3600)+' : '+Math.floor((props.total_spent_time%3600)/60)}</div>
            </div>
            <div className={'status'}>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={'line'}>
            <Line
              percent={props.progress}
              className={'line'}
              strokeWidth="2"
              trailWidth="1"
              trailColor="#D3D3D3"
              strokeColor="green"/>
          </div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-default"
            onClick={()=>this.props.onSubmit(this.state.id)}>Validate</button>

          <div style={{flex:1, padding:0, height:10}} className="progress-line progress">
            <div className="progress-bar progress-bar-success active"
              role="progressbar"
              aria-valuenow="45"
              aria-valuemin="0"
              style={{padding:0, maring:0, width: window.innerWidth/2}}
              aria-valuemax="100">
              <span className="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );

.Task {
  text-align: center;
  color:skyblue;
  float: left;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:80px;
  overflow:hidden;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
}
.container {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100%;
  float: left;
}
.App {
  text-align: center;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

Is there any simple documentation that explains clearly the behavior of the how html renders its elements... ?

Comment: What does the HTML output look like? Could you please post that?

Comment: @ObsidianAge just uploaded it

Comment: it's not clear from your question what specifically you're expecting to float, and what isn't floated since your screenshot is of an element that doesn't have float on it. Also your title says left, but your question says right. can you be more specific about all of these things?

Comment: so you see the dummy name and the another dummy name, and the paused label, the estimated, they are aligned vertically, I want to alight them horizontally, I tried to put justify-content , and alignments and float and all things I found on google, on the elements and their parents... almost every single element, I tried a lot of combinations, can't even remember, and they never changed, align vertically as rocks.. any way I ended up using bootstrap, col-xs-.... they are fixed now(only with bootstrap)...

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced a similar problem. I have fixed adding to container parent css:

`display: flex;`

[Flexbox](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox) for additional info